# Firebug's Computed tab no longer shows calculation of values

Tags: css, firebug

Can anyone tell me why the *Computed* panel in Firebug no longer shows the logical calculation of CSS property values?

More specific: Not to long ago, this tab could tell me why for instance a `font-size` is `30pt`s, by showing the list of involved CSS properties  like `body(font-size:1em)`, `#center(font-size:1.25em)`, `h1(font-size:1.5em)`, thus resulting in `1.875em` equalling `30pts`.

Now, in Firefox 54.0 and Firebug 2.0.19, the only information left in this tab is the end result of the equasion.

Is there a setting for hiding/showing the details?

Answer (score 0):

This is because [Firebug is discontinued and no longer maintained](http://getfirebug.com/) and a [change in the internal Firefox APIs in Firefox 50](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1225254) caused the *Computed* panel to not be able to display the style trace anymore.

[Mozilla recommends to use the Firefox internal Developer Tools](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/12/firebug-lives-on-in-firefox-devtools/) instead, which show the style trace:

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you want this details (see image ).

I can say that it work on Firefox 47 and firebug 2.0.19

I am still using old version Firefox <3 and Firebug.

[image]